# How to send data from parent process to child process and signal

Tags: c, linux, pipe

I got two processes run in parallel. I want that the parent will send some char to the child. I want to use pipe() and write from the parent and send signal to the child, then check from child if signal sent and read the char at the child process. How can i do that?

```
int run() {
    pid_t pid;
    int filds[2];
    pipe(filds);
    char *args[150] = {"./draw.out", NULL}; // child will run executable.
    char buff = '\0';

    if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {  // fork a child process/
        printf("*** ERROR: forking child process failed\n");
        exit(1);
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        execvp(args[0], args); // run program from the child process.
    } else {  // for the parent
            char btnPressed = getch();

            while (btnPressed != 'q'){
            btnPressed = getch(); // gets the char
            write(filds[1],buff, BUFF_SIZE); //write to the pipe.
            // how do i send safe signal to child?
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why send a signal? You already have a pipe to communicate with the child process. Why do you need another IPC mechanism?

Comment: Maybe i understood it wrong.. but i think using pipe i can just send data. After i send the data i need that inside my child process something will be done according to the data sent, of course if data didn't change nothing will happen at the child process. so i think that i need to send signal for the child to know something need to change..

Comment: Your child process can just read the data from the pipe. What do you mean by "if data didn't change"?

Comment: I want the child process to check if new data sent from parent, if and only if , parent sent new data. If the data sent to the pipe did not change i don't want the child to check for it,  because if data did not change the child will not to do anything with it. Once the parent send to the child new data inside the pipe, the child will be notified and check the data inside the pipe and deal with it..

Comment: You can write data to a pipe, and you can read data from a pipe. You cannot change data in the pipe. Your whole problem description makes no sense.

Comment: Why don't you use shared memory?

Comment: i think the OP misunderstands how `read` works.  There is no need for a signal, because when the child calls `read` on the pipe, that function will not return until some data is available.  This is called a "blocking read".

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you cannot use execvp and pipe together. Since execvp replaces the child process with another executable. It means that the parent and child process don't share the pipe anymore because the new process created by execvp has a different stack.

You can pass the data on shared memory and send a signal to the child. After the child reads the data, it can also send a signal to indicate that I got the data.

Comment: This is not correct.  Unless the close on exec flag is set on the pipe, the pipe is still shared.